# Как правильно обрабатывать php код после успешного if (event) JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть такой код из JS взят из API.

```
function PlayerjsEvents(event,id,info){
  if(event=="start"){
     после запуска код php должен обрабатываться посредством AJAX, так говорят.
  }
}
```

Будьте добры! Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно прописать такой код?

Comment: php код не обрабатывается посредством AJAX. php код обрабатывается на сервере. и возвращает результат своей работы скрипту.

Comment: @Ипатьев, а разве можно передать ajax допустим цифру 1 после этого запуска?

Comment: передать на сервер или с сервера данные?

Comment: @Arendach передать конечно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю что данная функция срабатывает после действия пользователя

```
function PlayerjsEvents(event,id,info){
  if(event=="start"){
     // делаем аякс запрос
     $.ajax({
         type: 'post', // тип запроса POST
         url: 'action.php', // страница которая будет обрабатывать запрос
         data: { // данные передаваемые на сервер
            id: 1
         },
         //  функция которая принимает ответ от сервера и ответ 
         // находится в аргументе answer
         success: function (answer){ 
            // если все правильно отработало то в консоли мы получим
            // нечто "вы передали id 1"
            console.log(answer);
         }
     });
  }
}
```

Теперь обработаем запрос при помощи php.

action.php

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    echo "вы передали id " . $_POST['id'];
} else {
    echo 'вы не передали id :((';
}

?>
```

То есть все данные которые мы отправили серверу находятся в глобальной переменной `$_POST`. Далее мы выполняем некоторые нужные нам действия и отдаем ответ(при помощи echo) а дальше на `JavaScript` выводим пользователю или не выводим.

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо, как вам поставить лайк или репутацию?

Comment: @OberynMartell Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".